How do debug failing startup application with Cinnamon?
I am using the Cinnamon desktop environment on Ubuntu 22.04.  I have a bunch of startup applications configured in the corresponding settings dialog.  Most of them are working as expected but one (workrave, in case it matters) doesn't, it simply doesn't get started.
I already verified that the configured command is correct.  When I execute it manually, workrave starts without any issues.
How can I debug this?  Is there some log in which failures of startup applications are recorded?  I already checked the log in cinnamon-looking-glass but no errors are listed there.
